# Print input boxes according to foreach loop value in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I am showing finger image for for all 10 fingers and 3 images for for each finger so total finger images will be 30. I am printing this using dynamic loop in table where I want show one input box for each finger so if there are two finger then two input box should show.

I have already decode object array and print it using foreach function but when I trying to show input box, it only showing one input box but I want more input boxes according array values.

This is my array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 1 [poz] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 1 [poz] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 1 [poz] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 2 [poz] => 1 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 2 [poz] => 2 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 0 [message] => Success [bio_id] => 1 [ref_id] => 2 [hand] => 1 [fin] => 2 [poz] => 3 ) )
```

This is my code:

```
$finger =  json_decode($blob->getallbiofile());
//print_r($finger);
$i = 0;
foreach($finger as $fing) {
if($fing->code == '0'){
    $i++;
?>
  <tr>
    <td class="">
<?php echo $finhelp->fingurevalue("hand", $fing->hand); ?> - 
<?php echo $finhelp->fingurevalue("fin", $fing->fin); ?> - 
<?php echo $finhelp->fingurevalue("poz", $fing->poz); ?></td>
    <td class="center">   
    <a href="showfinger?id=<?=$fing->bio_id?>" target="_blank">
     <img src="images/fingerprint.png" class="img-circle img-responsive reportfingerimage"></a>
 </td>
 <?php 
 if($i == $fing->fin) { ?>
        <td class="" rowspan="3">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="hidden" name="hand[]" value="<?=$fing->hand?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="finger[]" value="<?=$fing->fin?>">
    <input class="form-control fininput" id="ex1" name="finger_value[]" type="text" value="">
  </div>
    </td>
    <?php
    continue;
  }
?>


  </tr>

<?php 
}
} 
?>
```

Output I am getting like image link 
("https://eruditioninformatics.cf/imagelinks/WebAdminPanel.png") but I expect one more input box for second finger.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to check foreach loop for finger value every time and store it into an array. check if value not same with foreach loop value then print once input box and save another finger value into array. now final code is :

```
$i = 0;
foreach($finger as $fing) {
    $i++;
```

with

```
 $finarray = array();
foreach($finger as $fing) {
```

and:

```
if($i == $fing->fin) {
```

with:

```
if(!in_array($fing->fin, $finarray, true)) {
    $finarray[] = $fing->fin;
```

now I am getting input box for every finger.